# Jquery datatables: sort number with comma doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am trying to sort a column with numerical numbers with comma (,).

I am getting a wrong result using the `num-fmt` option:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
$('#test').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
         { targets: 4, type: 'num-fmt' }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [numeric-comma](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/numeric-comma) plugin to sort numbers correctly which use a comma as the decimal place.

Either include `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/numeric-comma.js` or use it inline as shown below:

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-comma-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace( /,/, "." );
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "numeric-comma-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "numeric-comma-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );

$('#test').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
         { targets: 4, type: 'numeric-comma' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: this replacement doesn't seem to work for 6+ digits where we have more than 1 comma. using a.replace( /,/g, "" ); seems to work for me.